# Konvajs (react-konva) dom portal position relative to parent group

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

I have a Konva Group which contains a portal so that I can render HTML Dom elements like this:
https://konvajs.org/docs/react/DOM_Portal.html

Inside my portal I have a Wavesufer.js waveform.

Is there any way to make the dom elements in the portal not position absolute?
In other words make them be inside the current konva group?
So that if I drag my konva group the portal stays inside and follows it.

I have not had any luck so far...

Right now my group with waveform is overflowing outside of the canvas and the konva group containing it stays hidden (and a scrollbar is added to container - good) but the dom waveform stays on top and the overflow is not hidden, it stays visible on top and overflows outside the konva container.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that you just want to make a DOM element that will follow a group position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can just read the position of the parent group, and apply for the same position the created DOM elements.

Or you can use `Html` component from [react-konva-utils library](https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva-utils)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Html } from "react-konva-utils";
import { Stage, Layer, Rect } from "react-konva";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
      <Layer>
        <Group x={50} y={50}>
          <Html>Square</Html>
          <Rect x={0} y={0} width={50} height={50} fill="red" shadowBlur={5} />
        <Group>
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```